# Extract City Name from a String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple companies, with a set of locations that are a string. Each have different numbers of spaces, but all end in a city name (which also contain a space occasionally).

My hope is that I can write SQL that results in only the city names in a new column.
The data would resemble these two columns

I've attempted `RIGHT(CLIENTNAME, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(CLIENTNAME) + ' ') - 1`
but that is not working. Is this possible?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a finite list of the upper case combinations in the middle there?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @jw11432 - no, unfortunately the list has no limit and will likely grow as we go through more acquisitions.

Comment: Your title and data don't reflect. `Des Moines` contains a space; the result should be `Moines`. I've changed the title to something more representative of the actual question.

Comment: Do you have a table of Cities? Then you would be able to achieve this. If not, how do *you* know what characters are part of the city's name, and, more importantly, how does SQL Server know?

Comment: @Larnu - no, that is not correct. Des Moines is a city. I know this because I know where my locations are. This is why I included that some cities also have spaces in the description.
SQL doesn't know - that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Which is why I said your title ("Identifying Last Space in String and Showing Any Text After Last Space") was incorrect, @debisstuck . If your title was correct, `Moines` is correct, because that's the text after the **last space**.

Comment: *"SQL doesn't know - that's why I am asking this question"* But you haven't explained how *you* know... If you don't know, SQL has no chance.

Comment: @Larnu - this is not helpful. I know because I took a geography class in middle school and I have a brick and mortar location in Des Moines. I can't teach that to sql.

Comment: But we can't send your SQL Server to a Geography class, so that isn't helpful to it, @debisstuck . Hence why I asked if you have a table of cities; I assume that as you didn't say "yes" the answer is "no". So start using that Geography class to create that table.

Comment: Then, once you have that table, simply `JOIN` to that table: `JOIN dbo.Cities C ON  YT.YourColumn LIKE '%' + C.CityName`. Ideally, however, you should be fixing your design to put the city name in a different column, or perhaps have a `FOREIGN KEY` `CONSTRAINT` to the `City` table. Then you can `JOIN` on that and no have a non-SARGable `ON` clause.

Comment: @Larnu your comments are coming through scattered, so I'm not sure if I have answered all your questions. No there is no cities table. The data above is what loads in the ETL process and I am need to break out the city to create the view.

Comment: He's saying if you build a table with the city names, you can use that as a lookup table to reference your `LIKE` operator and complete a `JOIN` to establish a source for definitively finding city names. Don't mean to step on toes Larnu, just seeing the opportunity to chime in with an attempt to help clarify. :)

Comment: @jw11432 - so if building a table of City names is the way - is there still a way to automate through sql extracting the city name into the dbo.Cities or would I manually need to maintain that?

I'm hoping tp find a way to adjust for this without manual edits to prevent user error.

Comment: It's one way. But presumably, the only maintenance of that table would be when new cities are added to the map. There should be some sites that contain lists of US cities

Comment: If there was an automated way, we wouldn't need the table, @debisstuck , as then you would be able to use that the extract the city directly from the string. The problem lies in that you *can't* identify the city, so you need to create a way to do so. In this case, creating a table of cities.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score -1):

This may also work. You'd need to go in and try to find other examples like Des Moines and you can add them to the `CASE` expression, and it could get a little lengthy, but this might work for you. It will need more testing, but with my limited testing, it appears to do it.

```
drop table if exists #test

create table #test (name varchar(50))
insert into #test values
('Company AB Roseville'),
('Company AB Des Moines'),
('Company CDE Houston')


select name=case when name like '%des moines%' then 'Des Moines'
        else ltrim(reverse(substring(reverse(name), 1, CHARINDEX(' ',reverse(name), 1))))
        end
from #test
```

Comment: Please use a DDL and sample data population from my answer.

Comment: @jw11432 - great! This will do the trick until the cities table is available and is working.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Location  VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('Company AB Roseville'),
('Company AB Des Moines'),
('Company CDE Houston'),
('Company CDE Los Angeles'),
('Company AB Salt Lake City');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*
    , City = c.query('data(/root/r[position() gt 2])').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(Location, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | Location | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company AB Roseville | Roseville |
| 2 | Company AB Des Moines | Des Moines |
| 3 | Company CDE Houston | Houston |
| 4 | Company CDE Los Angeles | Los Angeles |
| 5 | Company AB Salt Lake City | Salt Lake City |